# Google Cloud for Entity Extraction gives: Fail to load example and annotations. Error details: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-automl, automl

After successfully upload pdf documents data to Google Cloud Platform. The annotation tool gives the following error:

> Fail to load example and annotations. Error details: Cannot read property 'map' of null

(After clicking on Refresh the app got stuck)

[image]

Comment: could you give some more information on what and how are you trying to do? what particular product are you using? what do you mean by uploading pdf to GCP? NLP datasets should be JSON. If you would like to extract text from PDF you should use GCP Vision (https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf) instead of NLP!

Comment: I uploaded all training documents for Named Entity Extraction task as explained by Google AutoML (for NLP)  documentation. The status of the dataset is succesfully uploaded.  I followed this https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/prepare. After this I am not able to annotate the Named Entities the pdf files.

Comment: When I said uploading pdf to GCP I meant uploading the jsonlines files that have the URI of each pdf using the csv file having all the jsonl, etc. I followed the documentation.

Comment: Have you tried with a different pdf file(s) as a way of isolating the error?

Comment: For small (1 or 2 pages) pdf files it works. But for long (like 30 pages) pdf is kot working anymore.

Comment: I have been able to reproduce your error for large PDF's when reaching quota limit (2MB according to https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/quotas). Do you think this is the case? If it does not reach the quota limit (or is close to it) you might consider opening a public issue https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers